# Can we update the user status by bot token in slack app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, slack, slack-api

- I have a react app with a lot of users, and I want the user's status to change in Slack when the user logs in to my app. Is it possible with a bot token?
- and also how to get email of user who install my slack application

Answer (score 0):

> I have a react app with a lot of users, and I want the user's status
> to change in Slack when the user logs in to my app. Is it possible
> with a bot token?

You are able to update a user's status, however, you will not be able to do this with a bot token. Since you are taking actions on the user's behalf, you will need to use a user token. See more https://api.slack.com/methods/users.profile.set

> and also how to get email of user who install my slack application

You are not able to get the emails of user's on install, however, you are able to achieve this through other Slack events. For example when the user access the Slack's app Home.

1. First subscribe to the `app_home_opened` [event](https://api.slack.com/events/app_home_opened)
2. When the event happens, get the user ID of the slack user
3. Utilize the users.info method to gather info on the user. See more: https://api.slack.com/methods/users.info

   - For this to work, ensure you have the users:read:email scope for your bot. See more: https://api.slack.com/scopes/users:read.email